# 'float' object has no attribute 'item' when trying to map on series

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, int

When I try to convert float64 to float of a single value, it works fine -

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame()
a['Num']=['1','2','3','4']
a

def float(x):
    return x.item()

float(a['Num'].astype('float')[1])
```

output = 2.0 in 'float' format

When I try the same on series, it throws error ''float' object has no attribute 'item'' -

```
b=map(float,a['Num'].astype('float64'))
print(list(b))
```

Please help!

Comment: Without reading anything else, avoid calling `float` to something in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Do not name function "float" is not good idea.

In first case you work with numpy

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame()
a['Num']=['1','2','3','4']

def to_float(x):
    print(type(x))
    return x.item()

to_float(a['Num'].astype('float')[1])
```

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
2.0
```

But when you call

```
list(map(to_float,a['Num'].astype('float64')))
```

you have error because class float do not have attribute 'item'

```
<class 'float'>
```

You can try:

```
a['Num'].map(to_float)
```